# How to connect to private wifi network in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant, netctl, iwd

So I can't connect via:

---

- `nmtui`

just asking me to try again endlessly

---

- kde ui

no secrets were provided

---

- `iwd`

  ```
  station wlan0 connect SSID
  ```

(I enter password and get no output)

If I try this command again - I receive no output (even iwd not asking me for password)

(and network ofk doesn't connect)

---

- `wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "ssid" "mypassword")`

Returns:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWSCAN]: Device or resource busy
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-1 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="DM"
wlan0: Trying to associate with 84:d1:5a:d1:2a:69 (SSID='DM' freq=2427 MHz)
Failed to add supported operating classes IE
wlan0: Associated with 84:d1:5a:d1:2a:69
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=84:d1:5a:d1:2a:69 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="DM" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

---

- netctl start wireless-wpa

  - Job for netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

systemctl status "netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service":

```
× netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service - Networking for netctl profile wireless-wpa
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-04-16 08:22:18 +05; 2min 13s ago
       Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
    Process: 1874 ExecStart=/usr/lib/netctl/network start wireless-wpa (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1874 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 12ms

Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: Starting Networking for netctl profile wireless-wpa...
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs network[1874]: Profile 'wireless-wpa' does not exist or is not readable
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FA>
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile wireless-wpa.
```

journalctl -xeu "netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service":

```
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: Starting Networking for netctl profile wireless-wpa...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ A start job for unit netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1594.
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs network[1874]: Profile 'wireless-wpa' does not exist or is not readable
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FA>
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ The unit netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 08:22:18 archbtrfs systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile wireless-wpa.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░
░░ A start job for unit netctl@wireless\x2dwpa.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1594 and the job result is failed.
lines 1-3
```

---

Driver for wifi installed from here:

https://github.com/bserem/Realtek-RTL8822x-Linux

P.S. ssid is broadcasting and I can see it detected

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more information about the network. Is the SSID broadcast? Can you see it detected? The more detail you give, the better the chances someone might be able to help.